# Determine a determinant is divisible by 23 or not

Tags: matrices, determinant

Consider the fact that $25875, 46552, 41354, 48691, 95818$ are all divisible by $23$. Use this fact to determine if
\begin{vmatrix}
2 &5 &8 &7 &5 \\
4 &6 &5 &5 &2 \\
4 &1 &3 &5 &4 \\
4 &8 &6 &9 &1 \\
9 &5 &8 &1 &8
\end{vmatrix}
is divisible by 23 or not, without directly
evaluating the determinant.

Comment: You do not change the value of a determinant when you add to a column a linear combination of other columns. Can you exploit this fact by adding a well-chosen combination to the right column?

Comment: I think it is $10000 C_{1} + 1000 C_{2} + 100 C_{3} + 10 C_{4} + C_{5}$, so the right column is 
\begin{matrix}
25875 \\
46552 \\
41354 \\
48691 \\
95818
\end{matrix}

Answer (score 1):

A determinant of a matrix can be looked at as an (antisymmetric) **multilinear** function on the rows of that matrix. So:

$\det(23r_1,r_2,r_3,r_4,r_5)=23\det(r_1,r_2,r_3,r_4.r_5)$