# Rows of a Matrix is divisible by 19, show that its Determinant is also divisible by 19

Tags: determinant

I came across the following problem while self studying:

Let 
\begin{equation}
A = 
\begin{bmatrix}
2 & 1 & 3 & 7 & 5\\
3 & 8 & 7 & 9 & 8\\
3 & 4 & 1 & 6 & 2\\
4 & 0 & 2 & 2 & 3\\
7 & 9 & 1 & 5 & 4\\
\end{bmatrix}
\end{equation}

Use the fact that 21375, 38798, 34162, 40223, and 79154 are divisible by 19 to show, without evaluating, that $\det[A]$ is divisible by 19.

I noticed that each of these numbers are the entries in the rows of A, but I don't see how that helps me.

Comment: Closely related [Determinant divisible by 23](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/1567302/determine-a-determinant-is-divisible-by-23-or-not?rq=1)

Answer (score 15, accepted):

Note that $$10^{10} \det(A) = 10^{4+3+2+1+0} \det(A) =  \det \begin{pmatrix} 2 \cdot 10^{4} & 1\cdot 10^3 & 3\cdot 10^2 & 7\cdot 10 & 5 \\
3\cdot 10^{4} & 8 \cdot 10^3 & 7\cdot 10^2 & 9\cdot 10 & 8 \\
3\cdot 10^{4} & 4\cdot 10^3 & 1\cdot 10^2 & 6\cdot 10 & 2 \\
4\cdot 10^{4} & 0 \cdot 10^3 & 2 \cdot 10^2 & 2 \cdot 10 & 3 \\
7 \cdot 10^{4} & 9\cdot 10^3 & 1\cdot 10^2 & 5\cdot 10 & 4  \end{pmatrix}$$  $$ =  \det \begin{pmatrix} 21375 & 1\cdot 10^3 & 3\cdot 10^2 & 7\cdot 10 & 5 \\
38798 & 8 \cdot 10^3 & 7\cdot 10^2 & 9\cdot 10 & 8 \\
34162 & 4\cdot 10^3 & 1\cdot 10^2 & 6\cdot 10 & 2 \\
40223 & 0 \cdot 10^3 & 2 \cdot 10^2 & 2 \cdot 10 & 3 \\
79154 & 9\cdot 10^3 & 1\cdot 10^2 & 5\cdot 10 & 4  \end{pmatrix}$$ which is evidently divisibly by $19$ when calculated via expansion by minors along the first column.

Comment: Wow, a superb solution (and very fast indeed!)

Comment: Amazing! (+1) $ $

Comment: You don't need the $10^{10}$; you can just say $$ \det\begin{pmatrix} 2 & 1 & 3 & 7 & 5 \\ 3 & 8 & 7 & 9 & 8 \\ 3 & 4 & 1 & 6 & 2 \\ 4 & 0 & 2 & 2 & 3 \\ 7 & 9 & 1 & 5 & 4 \end{pmatrix} = \det\begin{pmatrix} 2 & 1 & 3 & 7 & 21375 \\ 3 & 8 & 7 & 9 & 38798 \\ 3 & 4 & 1 & 6 & 34162 \\ 4 & 0 & 2 & 2 & 40223 \\ 7 & 9 & 1 & 5 & 79154 \end{pmatrix} = 19 \det\begin{pmatrix} 2 & 1 & 3 & 7 & 1125 \\ 3 & 8 & 7 & 9 & 2042 \\ 3 & 4 & 1 & 6 & 1798 \\ 4 & 0 & 2 & 2 & 2117 \\ 7 & 9 & 1 & 5 & 4166 \end{pmatrix}$$

Comment: Can you justify what's going on between the second to last and last steps? How does that first column change like that?

Comment: @BrydenC: Basic determinant rule: You can add any scalar multiple of a column to any _other_ column without changing the determinant.

Comment: Yes, that makes sense to me now. Thank you.

Comment: @HenningMakholm You are right, but the answer appears clearer to me.